# Matlab - Manipulating datasets within subclass methods

Tags: matlab

I am having some difficulty designing a subclass of dataset in Matlab (R2010b). I am experienced programming Matlab, but new to using its OOP features. My constructor seems to be fine, but when I try to build some methods that access data in the dataset, I can't seem to get it to work. Here is an example:

```
classdef mydataset < dataset

properties
end

methods
    function [obj] = mydataset(obs,array)
        % obs is N x 1 cell array of strings
        % array is N x 2 double array
        obj = obj@dataset({array,'Field1','Field2'},'ObsNames',obs)
    end

    function [val] = computeValue(obj)
        col = obj.Field1;
        % I get an error above regardless of how I try to access the dataset.
        % e.g. col = double(obj(obs,'Field1')) also does not work.
        % Some more code using col to determine val
    end
end
end
```

In my method computeValue, I am trying to access the data in the dataset using dataset syntax, i.e. on the command line I could access Field1 using ".". It complains there is no method, property, or field Field1 for class mydataset. If I try the alternate syntax

```
col = double(obj(:,'Field1'));
```

it complains about the size of obj, e.g. "Index exceeds matrix dimensions".

I found a workaround using subsref:

```
methods
    function [val] = computeValue(obj)
        s.type = '.';
        s.subs = 'Field1';
        col = subsref(obj,s);
        % Some more code using col to determine val
    end
end
```

Although the workaround works, it is not very convenient and largely defeats the purpose of wanting a subclass of dataset. Is there some attribute or something simple I am missing?

Thank you very much.

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the complete code of your class. I suppose you didn't declare your property "factor" and try to access it.

Your class should look like this :

```
classdef MyClass
    properties
        factor;
    end

    methods
        function obj = MyClass(factor)
        % The constructor set the property factor
            obj.factor = factor;
        end

        function val = computeValue(obj)
            col = obj.factor;
            % ...
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I have revised my question to contain complete sample code and cleaned it up a bit.